# Filter out Soft Deletes from DbContext Set()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, dbcontext, soft-delete

How can I filter the `IsSoftDeleted` items out of this DbSet?

```
var type = GetTypeFromString("Whatever");
var whatevers = Set(type);
```

Method

```
public dynamic Set(Type type)
{
    var set = dbContext.Set(type);
    return set;
}
```

Model

```
public class Whatever : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
public class BaseEntity
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual bool? IsSoftDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: forgot to show `Whatever` derives from `BaseEntity`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Whatever class doesn't have any IsSoftDeleted property, so there's nothing to filter. I'm going to assume Whatever is derived from BaseEntity.

The main problem is that IQueryable<T>.Where doesn't actually exist: it's an extension method, and extension methods don't play nice with dynamic types. If the compiler can see a type implements IQueryable<T>, you can type var.Where(...) and have the compiler resolve it to System.Linq.Queryable.Where(var, ...). Since the type is dynamic in your example, the compiler doesn't know it implements IQueryable, and will report an error when you try to call Where.

You can cast the DbSet to IQueryable<BaseEntity> (as long as Type has BaseEntity as a base class), and call any filter on that. Do you actually use the dynamic type feature? If not, you can also consider dropping your custom Set function, and using the default DbContext.Set function.

```
var query = (from e in (IQueryable<BaseEntity>)dbContext.Set(type)
             where e.IsSoftDeleted != true
             select e);
```

Note: this is *not* the same as using dbContext.Set(type).Cast<BaseEntity>(): that won't work, because a DbSet<BaseEntity> and a DbSet<Whatever> are incompatible. It is only with IQueryable and other interfaces with "out" type arguments that you can do this.

Comment: Same idea at the same time :)

Comment: Yes, if this is the way to go, it does not surprise me that someone else came up with the same idea. It's mainly when I'm being stupid that I get surprised when others make the same mistakes. :)

Comment: I need the set of `Whatever` though. Is this only a set of `BaseEntity`? How would I access the properties like `Name`?

Comment: Every item in the result will be an instance of Whatever, and if you bind the result to a grid (or any control), you will see all properties of Whatever. But if you already know in the code that you want a query over Whatevers, wouldn't it be easier to use Set<Whatever>()? I thought the point of loading it from a string was to demonstrate that you want to support any arbitrary type. Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: You correctly interpreted my intention. I will only have the string. I just imagined the cast would trim off the derived properties. I'm still pretty new at this stuff. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, okay. No, IQueryable<BaseEntity> only lets the compiler in on the fact that each result is a BaseEntity, so that you can access the IsSoftDeleted property from your code. It doesn't mean the result can't be more than that. You can't type e.Name because you don't know from your code that the result will only hold Whatevers, but a grid (again, or similar) can show Name, because a grid will check the properties at runtime.

Comment: You guys are both very helpful. How am I supposed to know which answer to choose? On the one hand you explained the casting thing. On the other, @Slauma handles the nullable bool. Both were driving me nuts. Maybe I will flip a coin?? Thanks you guys.

Comment: x != true works with nullable bools, and translates to roughly !x.HasValue || x.Value != true. But both answers are essentially the same, so yes, flipping a coin seems fair :)

Comment: Oh wait -- yes, you're right. When x != true is translated to SQL, it has a different meaning than it does in plain C#.

Comment: @Benjamin: Accept hvd's answer. I remember that he was at least 30 seconds faster to submit his answer.

Comment: ok, `heads` = accept hvd's answer & `tails` = do what @Slauma said. Thanks again to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Set(Type type)` returns a non-generic `DbSet`. To apply your filter you must cast it to a generic `IQueryable<T>`:

```
var set = ((IQueryable<BaseEntity>)dbContext.Set(type))
              .Where(be => be.IsSoftDeleted.HasValue && !be.IsSoftDeleted.Value);
```

This works only if `type` is derived from `BaseEntity` or `BaseEntity` itself, otherwise you'll get a runtime exception.

The resulting `set` is of type `IQueryable<BaseEntity>`, so the question is, how useful this result is and how you can apply further filters for your derived entities like `Where(w => w.Name == "abc")`. At least, I could not get compilable code by making `set` of type `dynamic`. I also would not like to lose all strong typing.

Comment: You can cast a dynamic type to the right IQueryable interface too; the dynamic typing doesn't affect the answer, it's just useless here.

Comment: @hvd: Yes, true. I was wondering why he was using `dynamic` instead of `object` for example and I thought the idea was to write additional queries filters which would compile without casting and evaluate at runtime. But it doesn't compile apparently, it seems that a dynamic type in lambda expressions it not allowed. At least it didn't work in the simple example I tested.

Comment: Right, even if you explicitly call Queryable.Where instead of using it as an extension method, there's still the problem of figuring out how to type the filter expression. dynamic has at most one potential advantage that I can see: he can pass the result to a function accepting a typed IQueryable. I would not consider it an advantage, but he might. Side note, your where expression selects all entities that are soft deleted, I read the question the other way around, and select the ones that aren't soft deleted. I think both interpretations may be valid.

Comment: I need to select the type at run-time from a string and there are gazillions of DbSets. Is there a way to access the derived properties? It's not the `dynamic` that is important, just getting the correct filtered set of `Whatever`

Comment: @hvd: Thanks, I believe you read the question the correct way around. I've adjusted the Where clause.

Comment: @Benjamin: You would need an `IQueryable<T>` to access the properties of `T` for a query. You could cast to this (as pointed out by hvd in the first comment). The set itself is correctly filtered and only contains entities of the derived type. But you can't use strongly typed expressions if you start with `Set(Type type)` and don't cast to an `IQueryable<T>` of the derived type.